# how to fix the Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall' in python

Tags: python, ftp

I'm trying to reconnect to FTP server once in 2 minutes for accessing the newly generated files.But i'm facing attribute error.not able to identify the issue.can anyone suggest the right way of reconnecting to the FTP server.

Code:

```
def Connect1():
    ftp=FTP('ipaddress')
    ftp.login(username,password)
    files=ftp.dir()
    for file_ in natsorted(files):
            if file_.endswith('.sec.gz'):
            file_c=file_.split('/')
            file_d=file_c[3]
            print file_d
            files=date_b+'\\'+file_d
            print files
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR files', open('C:\\test\\'+file_d,   'wb').write)
            ftp.quit()
            time.sleep(120)
Connect1()
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-00293e7b319b> in <module>()
----> 1 Connect()
      2 
      3 
      4 

<ipython-input-19-0bc6dc053f87> in Connect()
     49             #output_filename1 = os.path.join(files)
     50             #print output_filename1
---> 51             ftp.retrbinary('RETR FAO05/DATA_INTV_NEW/'+files, open('C:\\test\\'+file_d, 'wb').write)
     52             ftp.quit()
     53             time.sleep(110)

C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.pyc in retrbinary(self, cmd, callback, blocksize, rest)
    411           The response code.
    412         """
--> 413         self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    414         conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
    415         while 1:

C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.pyc in voidcmd(self, cmd)
    251     def voidcmd(self, cmd):
    252         """Send a command and expect a response beginning with '2'."""
--> 253         self.putcmd(cmd)
    254         return self.voidresp()
    255 

C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.pyc in putcmd(self, line)
    179     def putcmd(self, line):
    180         if self.debugging: print '*cmd*', self.sanitize(line)
--> 181         self.putline(line)
    182 
    183     # Internal: return one line from the server, stripping CRLF.

C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.pyc in putline(self, line)
    174         line = line + CRLF
    175         if self.debugging > 1: print '*put*', self.sanitize(line)
--> 176         self.sock.sendall(line)
    177 
    178     # Internal: send one command to the server (through putline())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

Comment: *Please* first fix your code snippet's indentation - as is your code raises a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partly a wild guess since your code's indentation is totally broken, but if the call to `ftp.quit()` is really in your for loop, then no wonder that you get such an error on the second iteration. If you really want to disconnect from the server between each iteration, then you obviously have to reconnect at the beginning of the next iteration...